# How to write in console the Webelement content

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, test-automation-framework, test-strategy

I have following `source-code`:

```
main.container-fluid:nth-child(5)<main class="container-fluid ng-scope" ng-view=""><div class="row ng-scope">
<section class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <h3 ng-show="searchQuery" class="page-header page-header-sm ng-hide"><span translate="TITLE_SEARCH_RESULTS" class="ng-scope">Search Results</span> <span class="label label-default ng-binding" ng-bind-html="searchQuery"></span></h3>
    <h3 ng-show="!searchQuery" class="page-header page-header-sm ng-scope" translate="TITLE_ALL_PRODUCTS">All Products</h3>

    <div class="alert-info ng-hide" ng-show="confirmation">
        <p class="ng-binding"></p>
    </div>
</section>
```

(this is just a part of the `source code` here is the full [Source code](http://view-source:https://juice-shop.herokuapp.com/#/search))

Now I want to verify if the `source code` contains `All Products`.

Notice: I got, that text content on multi places same page so its important I select this one (for `XPath`).

This is my code I wrote so far:

```
 IList<IWebElement> links = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//h3[@class='page-header page-header-sm ng-scope']"));
     
            IList<IWebElement> listOflinks = new List<IWebElement>();

            for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
            {
                links = Driver.Instance.FindElements(By.XPath("//h3[@class='page-header page-header-sm ng-scope']"));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text))
                    //links[i].Click();
                    Console.WriteLine(links[i].ToString());
            }
```

Then I return in the console:

```
Element (id = c25b9ecd-b828-4353-a9d8-9f8a53b9cee9)
```

but the goal is instead to write in the console `All Products` + verify its there.

maybe could be done with `Assert`?

Could someone help me to correct the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by use

```
try
            {
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
                <br>console.WriteLine("Found All Products")


                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                element = null;
                <br>console.WriteLine("Did not found Webelement")

                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

An assert is a function that verifies if something happens or has happened.
If you are trying to use the script for exploratory purposes, you should extract the text of the element:

```
links[i].Text
```

Note: It can return an empty string, which may not be nice for exploratory testing, since your console will show nothing.

Maybe you should create a function to print this result propely for this case:

```
return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text)) ? "_NULL-Result" : links[i].Text;
```

Comment: I try to use ur   return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text)) ? "_NULL-Result" : links[i].Text; though It says cannot convert string to 'bool'.

Comment: Does the function you created return a bool or a string?
Notice the (string.IsNullOrEmpty(links[i].Text)) is just a conditional - the possible return values are strings ( "_NULL-Result" or links[i].Text).

Since C# is strongly typed, returning a bool would cause this error.